# How to call following oracle function in ADO.NET using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle, ado.net

How to call following oracle  function in ADO.NET using asp.net c#

```
 CREATE FUNCTION AuthenticateUser(UserName IN VARCHAR2,Password IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN NUMBER 
    IS
  Counts NUMBER;
  rval  Number;
   BEGIN 
       SELECT COUNT(USERNAMES) 
       INTO Counts 
       FROM tblUsers WHERE USERNAMES = UserName AND PASSWORDS = Password; 
       IF Counts = 1 THEN
      rval:=1;
       ELSE
     rval:=-1;
    END IF;
     RETURN(rval); 
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you would need the Oracle ADO.NET library (something like `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`?), and I'm not sure where you'd obtain that but Oracle should be able to help with it.  Once you have that, you would use the objects it provides to perform queries.  For example, if you want to fill a `DataSet` from a query it might look like this:

```
using (var connection = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleDB"].ConnectionString))
using (var command = new OracleCommand(query, connection))
using (var dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command))
using (var dataSet = new DataSet())
{
    connection.Open();
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
    connection.Close();
    return dataSet;
}
```

Notice the objects like `OracleConnection` and `OracleCommand` which come from that library.  As long as you have a valid Oracle connection string, those objects should work just fine:

```
<add name="OracleDB" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=some.host.name)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=DEV)));User Id=username;Password=password;"
  providerName="Oracle" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.  This presupposes you have set up your connection properly into the "conn" object.

```
 OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(@"select AuthenticateUser(:USER, :PASS) " +
     "from dual", conn);
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("USER", OracleDbType.VarChar));
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("PASS", OracleDbType.VarChar));
 cmd.Parameters[0].Value = "yoda";
 cmd.Parameters[1].Value = "jed1!";

 int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also, I know inline SQL is discouraged, but I was hopeful that this would demonstrate the concept.

Comment: can you guide me about insql?and your above code is inline sql

Comment: I just mean it's generally (although not universally) bad practice to put your literal SQL (in quotes) the way I did when I created the cmd object.  In this case, I really don't think it's that bad, and it keeps the example simple and demonstrates the point.  Truth be told, I'd probably leave the code like this.  If your SQL has 100 lines in it, this methodology leaves much to be desired, and there are better ways of doing it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you have a connection object and put in the correct user and password, this will work.

Comment: What are you used for oracle OPD.NET or ADO.NET for oracle

Comment: ODP.net.  devArt's dotConnect will also work.  I'm partial to dotConnect, but ODP.net definitely accesses all of the cool, low-level features of the Oracle DB